# module scrapy.selector not found

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to run simple program of scrapy but unable to execute it,following is the program

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
body = '<html><body><span>good</span></body></html>'
Selector(text=body).xpath('//span/text()').extract()



Following is the error,
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "scrapy.py", line 1, in <module>
from scrapy.selector import Selector
line 1, in <module>
from scrapy.selector import Selector
ImportError: No module named selector
```

Comment: This works for me in an `ipython` shell with `Scrapy 1.5.1`. Possible issues with your environment setups.

Comment: ok thank you pwinz

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is probably one frequent and difficult to debug: a module name conflict.

Your program file is probably named `scrapy.py`. Try renaming your program, and things should work.